# asp.net GetElementByid().value element/property not available

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Here's another one that's got me ripping what's left of my hair out.

My latest asp.net page is something I just threw together for an in-house database tool. It uses the standard VS 2010 design template, which means it uses the site.master page. I mention this because it may be relevant to my problem.

I'm using `asp:textbox` controls instead of `input type="text"`. When one textbox 'blurs,' I need to run a sub in code-behind that will do a database lookup based on the information typed in the textbox.

Everything I see about this is that I need to add a `asp:hiddenfield` to trigger the code-behind event to do the lookup. So I use `document.GetElementById` method in a JavaScript script to set the value in the hidden field. What it's supposed to do is: `document.GetElementById('HiddenInfo').value = "yada-yada"`.

My problem is that the VS development environment doesn't recognize the .value property for GetElelmentById command. For example, as is its wont, VS will give code hints as you type. When I get to where I want to insert the .value parameter, it doesn't show up on the list of suggestions. See illustration:

[image]

As you can see, typing the v doesn't bring up the .value parameter.

I've tried getting it by ClientID and by using jquery, and nothing works. The crazy thing is that I have done this before with anther web page I developed, but the only difference is that one did not have a site.master page.

I've spent hours trying to find the answer online, and nothing is quite exactly the same as my problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: it will not always show up in intellesense, but that doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: Intellisense often does not work well with Javascript.

Comment: Even typing it in fully it would not work.

Comment: Has same problem. Refer to this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101904/document-getelementbyidid-value-failing-in-asp-net-javascript-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hours and hours later, I finally found the answer. In the JavaScript function that changes the value of the HiddenInfo field, one line is added that (I guess) forces a postback, which then fires the _ValueChanged event in code behind:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function CheckCC() {
    document.getElementById('HiddenInfo').value="YES";
    <%= ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(HiddenInfo, "") %>;
}
```

I dug up the answer [here](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.client-side/changing-asp.net-hidden-field-in-javascri/266838).

Seems like a pretty obscure solution.

The odd thing is that in a previous asp.net design of mine, this wasn't necessary. That's what was really confusing me, and I still don't understand it. But at least I can move forward now.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's an asp .net element, so your going to have to get its clientid I believe. Here it is in jquery:

```
$('#<%=HiddenInfo.ClientID %>').val();
```

Comment: I had tried that, except I didn't put the hash tag at the beginning.

Comment: (the hash tag would be jquery-specific.)